# React - how to add to react DOM?

Tags: reactjs

newbie

I can create an element but how do I then add to that element ?

When I try

```
  <body>
    React....
    <div id="main_insert">
      <span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>    <script>
      let dish = React.createElement("h1", {id: 'top'}, "Baked Salmon");
      let ingredients = React.createElement("ul", {id: 'mainList'},
        React.createElement("li", null, "eggs"),
        React.createElement("li", null, "ham"),
        React.createElement("li", null, "spam")
      );

      ReactDOM.render(dish, document.getElementById('main_insert'));
      ReactDOM.render(ingredients,  document.getElementById('top'));
      // react and js code here
    </script>
  </body>
```

I get the ingredients but not the dish

My H1 does exist, but content is gone

[image]

Comment: Use JSX my friend.

Comment: Looks like the UL is there and it has something in it. Have you tried unfolding that node?

Comment: yeah jsx but I am learning without  it first for a bit of base knowledge

Comment: I believe this has to do with how `ReactDOM.render` works internally. If we comment the second render statement, `h1` tag data gets displayed properly. Now, since the list is getting displayed inside this `h1` tag, it does not take into account the data that was initially present within the `h1`. Same can be verified by having some content within the main_insert `div` and then trying to render only the `h1`. In this case also content within the main_insert `div` disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look a this reworked example - should work:

```
<body>
  React....
  <div id="main_insert">
    <span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>    
  <script>

    let ingredients = React.createElement("ul", {id: 'mainList'},
      React.createElement("li", null, "eggs"),
      React.createElement("li", null, "ham"),
      React.createElement("li", null, "spam"));

    let dish = React.createElement("h1", {id: 'top'},
     "Baked Salmon",
     ingredients);

    ReactDOM.render(dish, document.getElementById('main_insert'));
    // react and js code here

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** This is more of an analysis of the issue, @Piotr has already provided a workaround.

From [Reacts Website](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render)

> `ReactDOM.render()` controls the contents of the container node you pass
>   in. Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called

Lets look at the sequence of actions now:

1) No `render`  methods of the code are called ( both commented ):

[image: No render method called]

Here, we can see that the child `span` tag is getting displayed.

2) Now, we call the method `ReactDOM.render(dish, document.getElementById('main_insert'));`
This should insert the `h1` element while replacing the existing child elements.

[image: Render h1]

As expected, the child `span` tag gets replaced with the `h1` that we created.

3) Similarly, now when we call `ReactDOM.render(ingredients,  document.getElementById('top'));` , our new container node is the `h1` tag. Thus any content within `h1` gets replaced by the new element that we render within it like so :

[image: Render ul]